# Outputting client_secret from aws_cognito_user_pool_client

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

When I attempt to output the following, that value is empty string in remote state:

```
output "user_pool_client_secret" {
  value = aws_cognito_user_pool_client.some_name.client_secret
}
```

We are on Terraform v0.13.7 and that is outside my control, so upgrading to 0.15 for `nonsensitive()` is not an option (if this is even the issue).

How do I read this from remote state?

UPDATE: I've also attempted to consume the `client_secret` in an `aws_secretsmanager_secret_version` via `secret_string`, which responds with:

```
Error: error putting Secrets Manager Secret value: InvalidRequestException: You must provide either SecretString or SecretBinary.
```

Comment: The resource exists somewhere in the code?

Comment: @MarkoE yes, the resource exists!

Comment: You can use the secret in further calls but I doubt, you can print it as `output` irrespective of terraform version as I see `client_secret` being marked as sensitive in the [provider](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/blob/611b4737168f4f0051bb63ef221f0e76f156f392/internal/service/cognitoidp/user_pool_client.go#L114-L118)

Comment: Obviously doesn't apply to me, because I'm not on 0.15 or greater, but, wouldn't you be able to read it using the `nonsensitive()` call, @harshavmb?

Comment: Is it really blank in the state file? Or just not printed when you run `terraform output`? Have you tried running `terraform output user_pool_client_secret`? I have the same code in some Terraform and I can verify that it does indeed print the value when you specify it explicitly in the output command, as all Terraform sensitive values do.

Comment: @steamrolla, don't think so.. if you follow conversation [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/26185), if the field is marked sensitive in the provider, it won't print.. The above conversation is about terraform version `0.13.1`.

But, as @MarkB says you should be able to see the `client_secret` in plain text on state file..

Comment: @MarkB it really is blank in remote state outputs:

`"user_pool_client_secret": {
      "value": "",
      "type": "string"
    },`

Comment: It appears this is empty when consuming in another resource as well, question updated.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that it's not an issue with Terraform, it's a configuration issue with the resource itself. We have to explicitly ask the terraform resource to generate a secret, only then is it accessible.

Reference code

```
resource "aws_cognito_user_pool_client" "client" {
  name = "client"
  generate_secret = true

  user_pool_id = aws_cognito_user_pool.user_pool.id
}

# Secret is available at `aws_cognito_user_pool_client.client.client_secret`
```